# appying css using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html

```
<td>
     <a class="myBtn" href="/something/1">
</td>
```

and I want to use jquery to inject css to td element targeting myBtn class, so afterwards html should look like this

```
<td class="text-center">
     <a class="myBtn" href="/something/1">
</td>

$(".myBtn").parent().addClass('text-center');
```

css file has

```
.text-center{
    text-align:center!important;
}
```

Firebug doesn't report any errors, but td element appears without applied css class. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks right but questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: maybe the jquery ran before the html was done loading?

Comment: Maybe Firefox doesn't like when the `<a>` doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: Perhaps a space before `!`

Comment: Load the script on dom ready and its working fyn.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhavalr/rybguvuq/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit guessing, not knowing the whole code, but I think that the DOM isn't completely loaded when you are adding the class to the td.

So change it to:

```
$(function() {
   $(".myBtn").parent().addClass('text-center');
});
```

then the class will be added as soon as whole DOM is loaded.

Please note that you are missing the closing `</a>` tag as well!!